# Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code = 1, address = 0x0) issue is generated

Tags: c++

I'm using apple LLVM compiler for C++ development in Xcode. I initialise the `char pickbuf` variable and allocate the required memory I want to assign value 1 to second code of line there. But I'm getting a null pointer error: please help me.

2DCDP4.h

```
  class CDP : public Const2DCDP{

    struct PICK
        {
            short x;            // Transverse connector
            short y;            // Vertical direction consolidated
            unsigned char x0;   // Transverse reduction limit
            unsigned char y0;   // Longitudinal reduction limit
        } ;

    public:

        char*   pickbuf =new char[1];   // Overlapping buffer allocate some 
        PICK*   pickup =new PICK [1];       // Backtrace buffer

    }
void getProjection(void);
    };
```

2DCDP4.cpp

```
#include "2DCDP4.h"

void CDP::getProjection(void){
char    *before=pickbuf;
if( before[(j-1)*di + (i-1)] == 1) //**Thread 1 : EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code = 1, address = 0x0)**
{
//code 
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't allocated any memory to `pickbuf`, but try to access the memory at `pickbuf` on the 2nd line. To fix this, allocate some memory to `pickbuf` before the 2nd line:

```
char pickbuf[n];
```

or

```
char* pickbuf = new char[n];
```

Where `n` is a size large enough for you needs.

Comment: could you please find my edited code. after allocating memory im getting the error. thank you very much dude.

Comment: @RehanK You try to access the array at index `(j-1)*di + (i-1)` and it crashes, so `(j-1)*di + (i-1)` is giving you an invalid index (i.e. less than 0, or more than/equal to the array size). Use the LLVM debugger to find out what  `(j-1)*di + (i-1)` evaluates to and why.

Comment: could you please check this question dude http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832664/thread-1-exc-bad-access-code-2-address-0x8-error-c?noredirect=1#