# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS ( code=2,address=0x8) Error c++

Tags: c++

I'm developing c++ application . I have allocated memory but im getting the Error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS ( code=2,address=0x8)` in superfile.cpp. Here is my code :

*superfile.h*

```
struct Node{
        Voxel   *data;
        Node    *next;
    };
```

*superfile.cpp*

```
int* cnt =(int*)calloc(_width*_height,sizeof(int));
    Voxel *temp =(Voxel *)calloc(_width*_height,sizeof(Voxel)); 
    Node *list=(Node *)calloc(_width*_height*2,sizeof(Node));

list[(_width*_height)+l].next = list[_width*yy + xx].next->next; // Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS ( code=2,address=0x8) Error c++
```

after debugging the values of the variables are:

```
_width=60
_height=45
l=3
yy=4096
xx=-3345
```

Any idea what is going on ? Thank you

[image]

Comment: What are `xx` and `yy`?

Comment: @ForceBru xx= -3345 and yy =4096 and declared as int xx = (int)floor(x+0.5);
int yy = (int)floor(y+0.5);

Comment: I mean, where do they come from? Is that you who manually set these values or they're evaluated somehow?

Comment: @ForceBru after debugging these values are comming as it is , dude

Answer (score 2):

You're allocating not enough memory. Here, the size of `list` is 60*45*2=5400 elements. You're trying to access the 60*4096-3345=242415th element.

That's access to memory that doesn't belong to the memory associated with `list`. The 242415th element *doesn't exist*. That's SegmentationFault.

You'll need to use something like `calloc(_width*_height*100,sizeof(...));` to handle this. However, you'll waste lots of memory then.

Also, you never allocate memory for `next` and `next->next`. Try this

```
list[_width*yy + xx].next=calloc(50, sizeof(...));
list[_width*yy + xx].next->next=calloc(50, sizeof(...));
list[(_width*_height)+l].next = list[_width*yy + xx].next->next;
```

Here `50` is just random number, I'm not sure how much space does your `struct` consume.

Comment: still doesnt work dude. please find my edited question. thank you. i voted you.

Comment: @RehanK, I'd appreciate it if you stop calling me 'dude'

Answer (score 1):

You're dereferencing a null pointer here:

```
list[(_width*_height)+l].next = list[_width*yy + xx].next->next;
                                                         ^^^^^^
```

The value at `list[_width*yy + xx].next` is `0`, as initialized by `calloc`.

Comment: could you please link to read . im having lot of troubles regarding c++ memory handling and multitasking thank you

Comment: @RehanK First of all, this isn't C++ memory handling, this is C memory handling. C++ uses `new` and `delete`, not `calloc`. Secondly, in C++ you wouldn't even need to do manual memory handling... I'm not going to link you anything, you can Google all that you need yourself. StackOverflow even has [a list of good C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) which I recommend to check out and pick one. You should learn the basics of the language first before attempting manual memory management.